# Parsing restraints with bash and awk

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have restraints that look like

```
G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) E187CB/V78CB
A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

and I need to convert them with output:

```
assign (resid 5 and name C ) (resid 87 and name CD or resid 85 and name CB or resid 94 and name CB or resid 32 and name CB or resid 21 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
assign (resid 11 and name C ) (resid 158 and name C or resid 60 and name C or resid 152 and name C or resid 127 and name C or resid 159 and name C ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
assign (resid 13 and name C ) (resid 187 and name CB or resid 78 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) E187CB/V78CB
assign (resid 74 and name C ) (resid 131 and name CG1 or resid 135 and name CG2 or resid 78 and name CG1 ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

I have tried awk, but I couldn't figure out how to break up the array. Please help me convert this, it is brutal to do by hand.

Comment: This looks like it is going to boil down to a regular expression. If you've already tried something, you should include it in your question. Either way, you should make it explicitly clear how the input maps to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'restraints.file';

while (<$fh>) {
    my @values = map { /.(\d+)(\w+)/; $1, $2 } split '/', (split)[-1];
    my ( $resid, $name ) = /^[^-]+-.(\d+)(\w+)-/;
    print "assign (resid $resid and name $name ) (";
    print join ( " or ", 
        map  { "resid $values[$_] and name $values[$_ + 1]" } 
        grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#values 
    );
    print " ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! $_";
}
```

#### Output:

```
assign (resid 5 and name C ) (resid 87 and name CD or resid 85 and name CB or resid 94 and name CB or resid 32 and name CB or resid 21 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
assign (resid 11 and name C ) (resid 158 and name C or resid 60 and name C or resid 152 and name C or resid 127 and name C or resid 159 and name C ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
assign (resid 13 and name C ) (resid 187 and name CB or resid 78 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) E187CB/V78CB
assign (resid 74 and name C ) (resid 131 and name CG or resid 135 and name CG or resid 78 and name CG ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to split the first word on `-` and examine the 2nd element.
Then split the last word on `/` and examine each element.

Assuming GNU awk, read carefully about `split()` and `match()` from http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#String-Functions

---

Feeling generous:

```
gawk '
  function extract(str, fmt,      m) {
    if (match(str, /^.([0-9]+)(.+)/, m)) printf fmt, m[1], m[2]
  }
  {
    split($1, a, /-/)
    extract(a[2], "assign (resid %d and name %s ) (")
    n = split($NF, a, /\//)
    sep = ""
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      extract(a[i], sep "resid %d and name %s ")
      sep = "or "
    }
    print ") 3.5 2.5 8.5 !", $0
  }
'
```