# Restraint Parsing with Perl

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

My goal is to convert a restraint file which contains these four styles of entries:

```
T10N-Y9C-?: (111.699, 172.003, 26.159) L23CG/L50CG(notL23CG)
?-?-L147CB: (119.779, 178.656, 42.642) D107C/A77C/D110C
T89N-V88C-?: (120.308, 175.768, 130.859) orS106C_H41CG/F26CE1
G149N-G149CA-R109CD: (105.793, 45.249, 43.114)
```

With output where each of the styles is outputted as:

```
assign (resid 9 and name C ) (resid 23 and name CG or resid 50 and name CG ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! T10N-Y9C-?: (111.699, 172.003, 26.159) L23CG/L50CG(notL23CG)
assign (resid 107 and name C or resid 77 and name C or resid 110 and name C ) (resid 147 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! ?-?-L147CB: (119.779, 178.656, 42.642) D107C/A77C/D110C
assign (resid 88 and name C or resid 106 C ) (resid 41 and name CG or resid 26 and name CE1 ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! T89N-V88C-?: (120.308, 175.768, 130.859) orS106C_H41CG/F26CE1
assign (resid 149 and name CA ) (resid 109 and name CD ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! G149N-G149CA-R109CD: (105.793, 45.249, 43.114)
```

I have attempted many perl solutions, but I'm stuck. I am able to convert the first style restraint with [the following perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734167/parsing-restraints-with-bash-and-awk/25735444#25735444) suggested by jaypal in answer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734167/parsing-restraints-with-bash-and-awk):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
# 

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];

while (<$fh>) {
    my @values = map { /.(\d+)(\w+)/; $1, $2 } split '/', (split)[-1];
    my ( $resid, $name ) = /^[^-]+-.(\d+)(\w+)-/;
    print "assign (resid $resid and name $name ) (";
    print join ( " or ", 
        map  { "resid $values[$_] and name $values[$_ + 1]" } 
        grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#values 
    );
    print " ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! $_";
}
```

Perl is preferred, but python and awk are other ideas I have for this. Please help, I have a huge restraint file.

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific about which parts of the input you want translated into what, and when. Seems like you have some non-trivial logic involved as well.

Comment: The `(not    )` statements are experimental predications, but the restraint still needs to be printed before the `!`. These are examples of the 4 types of restraints that I have. The first style restraint is converted to the first line of the output with the perl code I have. But the other three restraint styles need to be converted to their corresponding output. (Like row 2 of input to row 2 of output in this case). I need to have the script determine the style and then proceed with an appropriate conversion for each line it reads.

Comment: You need to break your question down a lot more thoroughly as most people reading it are not going to know what differentiates the types of restraints -- you've given one example of each type of restraint and no description. If you've already managed to process one type of restraint, I'm sure you can do the others, or at least make an educated attempt that you can ask others for help with finishing.

Comment: If you're going to show code that was provided in an answer to a previous question, you should cite that user.  I've edited your question to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too broad and there is not nearly enough information to be able to reasonably assist you.

Additionally, the only code that you have shown was provided to you in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734167/parsing-restraints-with-bash-and-awk/25735444#25735444) to your previous question: [Parsing restraints with bash and awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734167/parsing-restraints-with-bash-and-awk).  This is not showing nearly enough effort to expect much assistance from others.

However, in a general sense, I would advise you to break down your problem into the pieces that you do know how to parse.  For example, there are three obvious sections to your data lines.  Create a regex to separate those out first.  Then you can attack each of those subproblems one at a time according to whatever formatting rules that you know.

The following demonstrates this initial parsing approach.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    # Separate 3 obvious sections of each line
    my ($name, $numbers, $data) = /^([^:]+): \s* \( ([\d\s.,-]+) \) \s* (\S*)/x
        or die "Unrecognized format at line $.: $_";

    # Parse numbers list into an array
    my @numbers = split /,\s*/, $numbers;

    # Output current variables - More parsing to come
    print <<"END_TEXT";
Line $.
   Name    = '$name'
   Numbers = '@numbers'
   Data    = '$data'
END_TEXT
}

__DATA__
T10N-Y9C-?: (111.699, 172.003, 26.159) L23CG/L50CG(notL23CG)
?-?-L147CB: (119.779, 178.656, 42.642) D107C/A77C/D110C
T89N-V88C-?: (120.308, 175.768, 130.859) orS106C_H41CG/F26CE1
G149N-G149CA-R109CD: (105.793, 45.249, 43.114)
```

Outputs:

```
Line 1
   Name    = 'T10N-Y9C-?'
   Numbers = '111.699 172.003 26.159'
   Data    = 'L23CG/L50CG(notL23CG)'
Line 2
   Name    = '?-?-L147CB'
   Numbers = '119.779 178.656 42.642'
   Data    = 'D107C/A77C/D110C'
Line 3
   Name    = 'T89N-V88C-?'
   Numbers = '120.308 175.768 130.859'
   Data    = 'orS106C_H41CG/F26CE1'
Line 4
   Name    = 'G149N-G149CA-R109CD'
   Numbers = '105.793 45.249 43.114'
   Data    = ''
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed help with. Thank you so much for the answer and the feedback/edit above.