# Replacing VCG1 or VCG2 with VCG* in perl script

Tags: bash, perl

With the help of jaypal in my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25735444/3767980) I was able to format my restraints for both for ambigous and unambigous cases. Let's consider the ambiguous here as it is the more difficult.

I have restraints that look like

```
G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) I187CG1/V78CG2
A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

and are subjected to the following perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
# 

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];

while (<$fh>) {
    my @values = map { /.(\d+)(\w+)/; $1, $2 } split '/', (split)[-1];
    my ( $resid, $name ) = /^[^-]+-.(\d+)(\w+)-/;
    print "assign (resid $resid and name $name ) (";
    print join ( " or ", 
        map  { "resid $values[$_] and name $values[$_ + 1]" } 
        grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#values 
    );
    print " ) 3.5 2.5 4.5 ! $_";
}
```

with output:

```
assign (resid 5 and name C ) (resid 87 and name CD or resid 85 and name CB or resid 94 and name CB or resid 32 and name CB or resid 21 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
assign (resid 11 and name C ) (resid 158 and name C or resid 60 and name C or resid 152 and name C or resid 127 and name C or resid 159 and name C ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
assign (resid 13 and name C ) (resid 187 and name CG1 or resid 78 and name CG2 ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) I187CG1/V78CG2
assign (resid 74 and name C ) (resid 131 and name CG1 or resid 135 and name CG2 or resid 78 and name CG1 ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

---

- What I need help with are lines containing entries that begin with a `V` followed by 2 or 3 digits and a `CG1` or a `CG2` after a `!`. Examples are V78CG2 or V135CG1.
- I need restraints corresponding entries to be treated with a wildcard. That is to say that I need restraints returned like:

---

```
assign (resid 5 and name C ) (resid 87 and name CD or resid 85 and name CB or resid 94 and name CB or resid 32 and name CB or resid 21 and name CB ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB
assign (resid 11 and name C ) (resid 158 and name C or resid 60 and name C or resid 152 and name C or resid 127 and name C or resid 159 and name C ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! L12N-T11C-?: (128.977, 175.109, 174.412) K158C/H60C/A152C/N127C/Y159C(notH60C)
assign (resid 13 and name C ) (resid 187 and name CG1 or resid 78 and name CG* ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! K14N-E13C-?: (117.377, 176.474, 29.823) I187CG1/V78CG2
assign (resid 74 and name C ) (resid 131 and name CG* or resid 135 and name CG* or resid 78 and name CG* ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! A75N-Q74C-?: (123.129, 177.253, 23.513) V131CG1/V135CG1/V78CG1
```

---

I need advice selecting matching lines and then applying the applied transfomation to the cluster input (before the `!`). I can find lines that match by a basic regex of `V.*CG[1-2]`.

I would like a solution that is in the above perl script.

If anything is unclear, please comment. I am still fairly new. I thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Do you understand how the script you have is working? If not, I would advise that you either try to figure it out or ask for an explanation so you can then modify the script to deal with these lines appropriately.

Comment: I understand how it works for everything except the map. I was able to generate a similar script for the ambiguous case. I have trouble with the map logic, but I have been reading on it. I really just need help bridging the gap between selecting the line and matching up the corresponding V CG restraints. I think it would be easiest to do it at the end. I am pretty confident that I could do this in bash, but I was hoping to use just one script. I can work on a bash solution to complement my question.

Comment: Which of the `map` lines? The first, with the regex in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of the script with an explanation of what is going on. The `my @values = map { ... } split '/', (split)[-1];` is a little tricky to understand, so I'll explain that separately:

`map` takes an array and applies whatever is within the braces to every member of the array, and outputs a new array. The two `split`s are used to chop up the line. If used without any arguments, `split` takes `$_` as input and splits on whitespace. Therefore, the first `split` takes `$_`, which is the current line, and splits it up by the spaces:

```
input:
'G6N-D5C-?: (116.663, 177.052, 29.149) K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB'

the array created by calling split:
'G6N-D5C-?:', '(116.663,', '177.052,', '29.149)', 'K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB'
```

The second `split` chops up the input on `/`; as input, it uses the last item in the array created by the first `split` -- i.e. `(split)` is a shorthand for "array created by splitting `$_` on whitespace", and `(split)[-1]` is the last element of the array.

```
input: 
K87CD/E85CB/E94CB/H32CB/Q21CB

array created by calling `split "/"`
'K87CD', 'E85CB', 'E94CB', 'H32CB', 'Q21CB'
```

The map command then applies a regex to every member of this array:

```
/.(\d+)(\w+)/; # match any character (.) followed by one or more digits (\d)  
               # followed by one or more alphanumeric (\w) characters.
```

The brackets capture the results into the read-only variables `$1` and `$2`. The second statement in the map adds those characters to the array that is being created by the `map` command. By default, perl puts the result of the last statement into the array, so you could do something like this:

```
my @arr = (1, 2, 3, 4);
my @two_times = map { $_ * 2 } @arr;
# @two_times is (2, 4, 6, 8)
```

(The "results" of the pattern match are actually $1 and $2, so the statement `$1, $2` to add them to the `@values` array is not strictly necessary.)

So `@values = map { /.(\d+)(\w+)/; $1, $2 } @array` captures the matches from each element in `@array` and puts them in `@values`.

I hope the rest of the script is understandable; if not, I recommend taking apart each command and using `Data::Dumper` to examine the results so you can work out what is going on.

To alter the script to treat the VnnCG1 / VnnCG2 entries differently, I added a line to the `map` command that finds any residue that matches the pattern and replaces it with `VnnCG*`. I then altered the matching regex so it would grab the appropriate pieces of the residue name but would not grab inappropriate data (such as the `(notB28DG)`). Here is the new script with comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature ':5.10';
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', $ARGV[0];

while (<$fh>) {

    # a brief guide to regexps:
    # \d     = digits
    # \w     = digits or letters or _
    # [ ]    = match any of the characters within these brackets
    # ( )    = capture the value in these brackets, save it to $1, $2, $3, etc.
    #        (brackets are also used for alternation, but not in this case)
    # *      = match 0 or 1 times
    # +      = match 1 or more times
    # \*     = match the character *
    # s/ / / = search and replace
    # /x     = ignore whitespace

    my @values = map {
        # find the pattern
        s/V     # V
        (\d+)   # one or more digits; the brackets mean we capture the value
                # and it gets saved in $1
        CG      # CG
        [12]    # either 1 or 2
        /V$1CG*/x; #replace with V $1 CG *

        # find the pattern
        /.       # any character
        (\d+)    # one or more digits; capture the value in $1
        ([A-Z][\w\*]*) # a letter followed by zero or more alphanum or * 
        /x;            # the value is captured in $2

        # put $1 and $2 into the array we're building
        $1, $2
        } split '/', (split)[-1];

    my ( $resid, $name ) = /^[^-]+-.(\d+)(\w+)-/;
    # compose the new string
    my $str = "assign (resid $resid and name $name ) ("
    . join ( " or ",
        map  { "resid $values[$_] and name $values[$_ + 1]" }
        grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#values
    )
    . " ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! $_";
    # "say" prints out the string to STDERR and automatically adds a carriage return
    say $str;
}
```

Short version of the 'core' script without comments:

```
foreach (@data) {
    my @values = map {
        s/V(\d+)CG[12]/V$1CG*/; /.(\d+)([A-Z][\w\*]*)/;
        } split '/', (split)[-1];
    my ( $resid, $name ) = /^[^-]+-.(\d+)(\w+)-/;
    say "assign (resid $resid and name $name ) ("
    . join ( " or ",
        map  { "resid $values[$_] and name $values[$_ + 1]" }
        grep { not $_ % 2 } 0 .. $#values
    )
    . " ) 3.5 2.5 8.5 ! $_";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide such a rich answer.

Comment: :) I hope that it will also help you with future programming problems!

Comment: Thanks again, I was able to do the other type of restraint on my own today because of your great answer (Even if it did take most of the day, haha).. :)

Comment: That's great--and it will get quicker and easier! :D